# Installing SSL on Jenkins from Script Console

Tags: ssl, jenkins, groovy

I've got a Jenkins instance with no security, as in `<securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None"/>`. I need to setup SSL certificates, but all I've got is the Script Console. There are bits and pieces of information online on how to do various parts of it, but I could not find a guide on how to setup SSL from ground up, starting with setting up keystore using only groovy console. Can anyone point me in the right direction? If nothing else I'd like to be able to at least get through setting up keystore and things might get easier from there. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking.

If "setting up SSL certificates" means making the Jenkins web UI accessible via an https:// URL, that's not something that can be done within Jenkins itself.  You would need to configure the web server that you're using (e.g. nginx, Apache, Tomcat…) separately.

There is [documentation on the wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) covering setting up HTTPS if you're using the web server built in to the Jenkins WAR file.

Or — since you mention security realms — if you're wanting to use client-side SSL certificates to authenticate your users, this is again something you'd need to set up on your web server, but there is the [Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/reverse-proxy-auth-plugin) which lets you delegate user authentication to your web server.

But none of this is related to the Jenkins Script Console.

Comment: Thanks, I was a little bit confused, but found the answer on GitHub - see the answer I posted below.

Comment: Right, that's the same as the wiki documentation I pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found this link that gave me everything I needed, https://github.com/hughperkins/howto-jenkins-ssl. I logged on to the VM Jenkins was running on and was able to generate keys and self-signed certificate with openssl, as well as do all the configuration with just a handful of commands listed in the link. None of this involved the script console.